# auto_ptr in a class not returning from a source function

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

Consider the following code:

```
#include<memory>

struct A {
    std::auto_ptr<int> i;
};

A F() {
    A a;
    return a;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    A a = F();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling I receive a compilation error, (see [here](https://ideone.com/H1GASw)):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(A)’
     A a = F();
             ^
```

To my understanding, `A::A(A)` isn't even allowed to exist, so why is the compiler requesting it? Secondly, why is it not using RVO?

---

If it is because a `std::auto_ptr` cannot be returned from a function, why does the following compile and run?

```
#include<memory>

std::auto_ptr<int> F() {
    std::auto_ptr<int> ap;
    return ap;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::auto_ptr<int> ap = F();
    return 0;
}
```

---

I cannot use C++11 in my current work unfortunately, hence the use of `auto_ptr`.

Comment: RVO requires an accessible copy-constructor to be present, even if it's not used.

Comment: AFAIK `std::auto_ptr` is a complete and unreliable mess. You are probably better off it. You can use `boost::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: @chris, isn't the default copy-constructor present? `std::auto_ptr` can be returned raw from a function.

Comment: @Cramer, Keep in mind `std::auto_ptr`'s constructors do "moves" and consequently take a non-const reference. Your link's error tells you that `A` gets the same constructor: one that takes a non-const `A &`. `F()` cannot bind to `A &`.

Comment: @chris, is `auto_ptr` non-copyable? Is this the reason why you need an explicit copy ctor? Because if you replace e.g. `std::auto_ptr<int> i;` by some POD, then RVO works without the need of explicitly declaring a copy ctor. At least that's what I understand from pre-C++11 "moves".

Comment: @vsoftco, It's "copyable", but doesn't support the traditional `Class(const Class &)` copy-constructor because of how it implements the "copy". Thus, the class with that as a member cannot get a traditional default copy-constructor.

Comment: @chris, yeah that's what I thought, was just editing my comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Cramer `std::shared_ptr` was introduced in the C++2003 tr1, even most older compilers have it although it may be in the `std::tr1::` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I tried searching but couldn't find a relevant Q&A, even though I know this is a duplicate. So instead I'm answering instead of voting to close as a duplicate. Apologies.

---

The reason it needs a copy constructor is because the line:

```
A a = F();
```

is really (from the compiler's perspective):

```
A a(F());
```

even if copy elision/RVO is used. That is, the compiler **does not** do:

```
// This is NOT what the compiler does for A a = F();
A a;
a = F();
```

Even with copy elision/RVO, `A a(F());` won't work. From a C++ standards perspective, the code needs to be legal, whether or not the compiler does copy elision. Copy elision doesn't relax the requirement of needing a copy constructor (even if it doesn't actually use it; it still needs to be there in order to ensure "legality" of the code).

This doesn't work, because `std::auto_ptr`'s copy constructor doesn't take a `const` reference, so `A`'s copy constructor doesn't exist. `F()` returns a temporary `A`, which can only be captured by a `const` reference, which means that line of code is trying to use a non-existent copy constructor.

Comment: But then why then is `std::auto_ptr<int> F()` legal? If you remove the class `A` and just pass the 'raw' `auto_ptr` around it never complains. Note it's not asking for `A(A&)`, its specifically asking for `A(A)`, which is non-sensical. If you implement `A(A&)` (which is implemented automatically if you see the error) it still won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler normally makes the default constructor

```
A(const A&)
```

However in this case it is not possible as there is no `auto_ptr::auto_ptr(const auto_ptr &rhs)` so it creates the following instead:

```
A(A&)
```

Now, when the `F` returns it will not let the return value `a` be modified (I think because it might be a persisting object such as a global or a reference). When it finds no `A(const A&)` it will instead look for `A(A)` as that's the only other way to return the value without modifying `a` (even though it's stupid). Even using RVO, it must still be valid code as @Cornstalks mentions in his answer (to an extent, see below).

`auto_ptr` gets around this by creating a temporary `auto_ptr_ref` object using the following ([ref](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00761_source.html))

```
auto_ptr::operator auto_ptr_ref()
auto_ptr(auto_ptr_ref)
```

For some reason, the compiler accepts the typecast to `auto_ptr_ref` despite it not being a `const` function and rejecting the use of `A(A&)`.

---

To get around this issue one can simply declare `A(const A&)` without implementing it

```
struct A {
    A() { }
    A(const A&);
    std::auto_ptr<int> i;
};
```

The compiler thinks that the return is legal but applies RVO before the linker sees it and so the missing implementation is never needed. Of course it precludes the use of

```
A a;
A b(a);
```

An inelegant fix, but effective none the less.

Comment: @Cornstalks fixed, do you know why it's allowed to use the typecast but not the copy-constructor?